# How can I use a custom font in a Silverlight application's TextBlock?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to give my TextBlock a custom font that I downloaded from the internet, but in the FontFamily category I only see about 9 fonts, and no option to load a new one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the font to your project, then you can reference it from the FontFamily property.

See [Silverlight Tip of the Day #46 – Font Support in Silverlight](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/09/09/97060.aspx) for all the fun details.